# Install multiple instance of MySQL on macos Catalina

Tags: mysql, macos, macos-catalina

I install MYSQL on my Mac (Catalina) via the homebrew. It works but I wanna install both MYSQL5.7 and MYSQL8.0, homebrew didn't help

Is there any instruction for Mac please guide me?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [two installs of mysql on osx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460044/two-installs-of-mysql-on-osx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use docker or DBngin

- Nice UI [DBngin](https://dbngin.com/)
- Using docker and map 2 instances to 2 separate ports. ie 3306 and 3307

  - brew install docker
  - docker run --name mysql5 -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=YourPassword -d mysql:5
  - docker run --name mysql8 -p 127.0.0.1:3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=YourPassword -d mysql:8

It will map your MYSQL in docker (port 3306) to your local 3306 and 3307 for your instances

Comment: How to config my.ini? Like, I want to add some extra MYSQL's configurations on each instance

Comment: DBngin, I haven't tried it yet but with docker, you can add a custom MYSQL's configuration. Here are parameters that should help you https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql